# Looping through Trigger new Field Value Issue

Tags: apex, trigger, fields, custom, loop

Hopefully this is a simple oversight on my part, but I can not see why when I loop through my Trigger.new, one of my field values is not populating.

The field (contact's-> account's-> Web_Id_NatFund__c field) 100% has a value, I can query for it and the value shows. But when I run this:

```
for(Contact c : Trigger.New) {
    if (c.Account.Web_Id_NatFund__c != NULL) {....
```

c.Account.Web_Id_NatFund__c comes in as a `null`.

Is there an explanation for this?

My only thought is when I `system.debug` the `Trigger.new` or the values of the `Contact`, the actual field name is `AccountId`. Is this the possible issue?

```
Trigger New:: (Contact:{Id=0030t000001rJ65AAE, IsDeleted=false, MasterRecordId=null, AccountId=0010t000002mBnFAAU,....
```

When I mess around with `c.AccountId.Web_Id_NatFund__c`, it rejects the AccountId field saying `Error:A non foreign key field cannot be referenced in a path expression: AccountId`. I am able to pull out other custom and standard field values of the Contact.

Shouldn't it just understand what `c.Account.AnyFieldNameCustomOrStandard` is?

Comment: Related objects are not populated for the object in a trigger, so you'll need to explicitly retrieve the accounts for your contacts.

Comment: ahh thank you so much I thought I was going crazy. That is interesting! For anyone reading, I will query for the field value and ensure there is not a null value before entering the initial conditional. If you want to post that as the answer I will mark correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Related objects are not populated for the object in a trigger, so you'll need to explicitly retrieve the accounts for your contacts.  You need to loop through your contacts to collect the account IDs, then retrieve the accounts into a `Map<Id, Account>` so you can reference them using Contact.AccountId

Comment: Another quick-and-dirty test: If you need to use more than one dot/period/full-stop to access the field (i.e. `c.Account.Web_Id_NatFund__c`, which uses 2 periods), then it is not available in trigger context variables like `Trigger.new`, and you need to query to get that data.

Comment: @DerekF how would I go about querying the data? I am unable to query inside the loop but I would need each Contact's Account Id...do you think the best idea would be to save the Contact's Id and the AccountId into a map and then look at the map on the outside of the loop?

Comment: @Olivia that is correct, I updated my answer to include that.

Comment: @Olivia I really think you're trying to over-complicate matters here. It really is just a basic query. Instead of using `Trigger.new` for your loop, use a soql-for-loop. Use dot-notation in the query to grab the fields from `Account` that you want. Use `Trigger.new` to control the `Contact` records that you query for.

Comment: @DerekF you are right, I am way over complicating it. I used: `for(Contact c : [SELECT Id,pi__url__c, Account.Web_Id_NatFund__c FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new])` and was able to retrieve all the data necessary.